# Swagger and content negotiation configuration not working together

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, content-negotiation

In my spring boot application, I have swagger configuration and content negotiation configuration. For the swagger to work, I need to comment out content negotiation. How to fix this? Thanks for your time.

***Update:*** If I remove the @EnableWebMvc the swagger works. But path extension stops working meaning http://localhost:8080/v1/20190731.xml. I included the entire code for swagger and content negotiation

***Swagger Configuration class***

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration {
     @Bean
        public Docket api() { 
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
              .select()                                  
              .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.i"))             
              .paths(PathSelectors.any())
              .build()
              .apiInfo(getMetaData());                                           
        }

public ApiInfo getMetaData() {
    String title = "REST API";
    String description = "Rest interface services";
    String version = "1.0";
    String termsOfServiceUrl = "https://xcv.com/terms.html";
    Contact contact = new Contact("Pro rol",
            "https:/lay/C2450",
            "dl.gt.gcom");
    String license = "ci 2019";
    String licenseUrl = "i/terms.html";

    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title(title)
            .contact(contact)
            .description(description)
            .license(license)
            .licenseUrl(licenseUrl)
            .version(version)
            .termsOfServiceUrl(termsOfServiceUrl)
            .build();
}
```

}

***Content Negotiation Config class***

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    MdhTotemConfiguration mdhTotemConfiguration;

    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new CsvHttpMessageConverter(mdhTotemConfiguration));
    }

    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(true)
        .favorParameter(true).parameterName("mediaType").ignoreAcceptHeader(false)
                .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .mediaType("csv",new MediaType("text", "csv"));

    }
}
```

Comment: What issue are you having? Swagger and content negotiation work just fine together. I use it on my project.

Comment: I am getting swagger page not found error

Comment: @SledgeHammer I included the entire code for content negotiation and swagger. Please look at it when you get a chance.